# django two type of accounts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create two type of user account in django 1.6

So that I am following one tutorial [MULTIPLE USER TYPES IN DJANGO >=1.5](http://michalcodes4life.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/multiple-user-types-in-django-1-6/)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    password = models.CharField(
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True) 
class LinkedInUser(CustomUser):
    linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'LinkedIn User'

class FacebookUser(CustomUser):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Facebook User'
```

Now I am getting the error is:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'password' in class
>   'CustomUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class
>   'AbstractUser'

for that i am removing everything from user profile.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

but now the error is:

```
(env)refei@user-desktop:~/studio/myproject$ python manage.py syncdb
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
frontend.profile: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
frontend.profile: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
```

Can you please guide me, Where I am wrong? And how to create two type of account in django 1.6?

**Edited**
After given the AUTH_USER_MODEL in admin here is another error.

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>   admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model firstapp.CustomUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
>   auth.user: Model has been swapped out for 'firstapp.CustomUser' which has not been installed or is abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am marking your errors in code as comments:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):   # one
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) # two
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30) # three
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True) # four
```

In `comment one` you are extending `AbstructUser` model, then why are you adding user as OneToOne relation in the model (`in comment two`), you have to use either one of those. Check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

`comment three` and `comment four` are unnecessary here as django auth user model provides those(email/password).

For second section:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

You must declare AUTH_USER_MODEL on your settings.py. In your case:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.CustomUser'
```

Comment: oh .,.. now i given the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings and i am getting one command error... i update my question with that error

Comment: check if `firstapp` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` and secondly please make sure your model is not abstruct( add fields instead of using `pass`) @user3895077